# How can I create a checklist in Google Keep from a Google Sheets spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-keep

I exported my list of books I own from Shelfari, and want to create checklists in Keep for certain authors that will make it easier to browse second hand stores and not buy things I already have. I can get the complete list of books from the authors' websites (or Wikipedia), but it I am struggling with connecting the two Google services.

If I wasn't sitting in a Hotel on vacation I would actually code something that uses APIs to do it, but I'm pressed on time. Is there a built-in way to do this?

Comment: There is now an unofficial and somewhat undocumented Google Keep API client created by the community reverse engineering the API.  You could potentially use this along to connect with Google Sheets programmatically.  https://github.com/kiwiz/gkeepapi

Answer (score 8):

You may use the Web version of Keep (https://keep.google.com) and copy/paste all items directly there and it will create a checkbox on each line you pasted. 
It will sync automatically with the mobile app.

Comment: This is almost certainly the way I'd tackle the issue.